# counting number of steps to reduce integer to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

so I'm new to learning `def function()` in python. And I'm implementing a code that counts the number of steps to reduce an integer to zero.

I have defined a function that makes a list of the integer input by the user, and another function that counts the steps.

the problem is in the second function: currently`numberOfSteps` only takes the first input, but it needs to take all user inputs listed by the first function `UserEntryList`

```
def UserEntryList ():
    integerEntry = input("Please enter: ")
    integerEntry = integerEntry.split()
    listOfInt = []
    for i in integerEntry:
        try:
            listOfInt.append(int(i))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return(listOfInt)



def numberOfSteps():
    counter = 0
    listofnumbers = UserEntryList()
    for i in listofnumbers:
        while i > 0:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                i /= 2
            else:
                i -= 1
            counter += 1

        return counter
```

desired output:

```
Please enter a set of space-separated positive integers: 10 15 59
[(10, 5), (15, 7), (59, 10)]
```

Comment: call the function - put `numberOfSteps()` at the bottom of your file with no indentation.

Comment: Arguments/parameters, you don't have/use/need any?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.  You need to repeat your educational materials on functions, to gain enough understanding of this basic programming technique.

Comment: @Macattack these arguments/parameters that I don't understand how to use

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @philipxy Ok this makes sense, thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, couple of things:

- always use snake_case in Python, instead of camelCase or PascalCase. More on naming conventions in Python [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
- return statement in Python should not be enclosed by brackets, unless you're returning a tuple. More on this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/).
- in the function `numberOfSteps()`, you have entered the return statement within the for loop. this will not work, as the program will terminate after processing the first item in your loop. So, append your results from each iteration to a list/dict (dict example is shown below.) and return it in the end after the for loop has completed.

```
def numberOfSteps():
    counter = 0
    listofnumbers = UserEntryList()
    counter_dict = {}
    for i in listofnumbers:
        temp = i
        while i > 0:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                i /= 2
            else:
                i -= 1
            counter += 1
        counter_dict[temp] = counter
    return counter_dict
```

And to answer your question, you can just do append this at the end of your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    counter = numberOfSteps()
    print("Counter = " + str(counter))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proper way of defining the main function and call sub-function from main function. You will not need to pass any arguments to any functions since you are directly calling UserEntryList from numberOfSteps, which gets executed from the main function.

```
def UserEntryList ():
integerEntry = input("Please enter: ")
integerEntry = integerEntry.split()
listOfInt = []
for i in integerEntry:
    try:
        listOfInt.append(int(i))
    except ValueError:
        continue
return(listOfInt)



def numberOfSteps():
    counter = 0
    listofnumbers = UserEntryList()
    for i in listofnumbers:
        while i > 0:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                i /= 2
            else:
                i -= 1
            counter += 1

        return counter

def main():
    counter = numberOfSteps()
    print("Counter = " + str(counter))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: is there a way to input multiple numbers e.g. ``` Please enter: 10 15 59``` and to count the number of steps? for  each?

Comment: yes you can ask the user a string of number separated by comma and then split the string by comma to create list of strings of number. Then you can loop through each number in the list and perform above logic